# React dobble update so my useContext = undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-context

Hi i have a problem with my react app, I'm using useContext to parse my user to a voting site, but I have a small problem, my app is dobble loading, then my context turns to undefined, i can see the user at the first console.log but i cannot access it.

````
const { user, setUser } = useContext(UserContext)
const [medarbejdere, setMedarbejdere] = useState({})

const userLogIn = document.getElementById('id').value;
const user = medarbejdere?.filter(userid => userid.id === parseInt(userLogIn)).map(currentUser => console.log(currentUser)) 
        
setUser(user);
navigate("/votingsite")```
````

Comment: Please explain what "dobble" means?

Comment: it means thats its cumming out twice in the log

Comment: Did you mean "double"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` is a void return, you are mapping a `currentUser` value to undefined and then updating likely the `user` state to an array of undefined values. Don't use `Array.prototype.map` for side-effects like console logging a value.

```
const { user, setUser } = useContext(UserContext);
const [medarbejdere, setMedarbejdere] = useState({});

const userLogIn = document.getElementById('id').value;
const user = medarbejdere?.filter(userid => userid.id === parseInt(userLogIn));

// console log the entire `user` array
console.log(user);

// or use `Array.protype.forEach` to issue side-effect on each element
user.forEach(currentUser => console.log(currentUser));
```

You also may be seeing the `setUser` and `navigate` calls as unintentional side-effects because they are in the component body. These should be in a callback or `useEffect` hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setUser(user);
  navigate("/votingsite");
}, []);
```